# GraphQL react-apollo - is it okay to export/import client directly?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have an apollo setup file, `services/apollo.js`, where I export the client:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: ApolloLink.from([stateLink, httpLink])
})

export default client
```

and I then import that and use it as normal elsewhere:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>
</BrowserRouter>
```

If I want to use the client directly (for manually firing off a query for example), is it okay to import it directly into the file, rather than accessing it via `ApolloConsumer`?

```
import client from 'services/apollo'

export const getSomeData = async () => {
  const { data } = await client.query({ ... })

  console.log(data)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, that should be fine.

This blog post mentions using a singleton for Apollo:

> I use a singleton with a unique apollo client to keep a unique cache
>   and use in all code.

https://cheesecakelabs.com/blog/apollo-graphql-client-makes-api-integration-breeze/

Comment: Thanks for the great article 